# How to retrieve multiple page REST query quickly

Tags: python, python-requests, github-api

I'm working with the github API in python.

Github limits most GET responses to a max of 100 items/per page. Each request takes a couple of seconds, so a 20 page request is not a great user experience.

What is the pythonic way of making the requests concurrently.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do it.  The easiest is probably to use something like the [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module (or the [backported version](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/futures) for Python 2.x).

However, one very important thing to keep in mind is that GitHub apply rate limits to their API, and you can't just make as many requests as you like without hitting up against those rate limits.  So make sure to check for HTTP/429 errors and back off accordingly.